# Get and set background color of QFrame or QGroupBox with ONLY palette

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyside2

How can I get and set the background color of a `QFrame` and `QGroupBox` with palettes? From what I can tell I can effect them with `QPalette.ColorRole.Background`, but this also effects the window color as well, so instead of getting a lighter shade, the whole interface is set as a solid color. Is there a way to effect them separately?

I know I can use stylesheets, but in this case I want to achieve it only with palettes if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
from PySide import QtWidgets, QtGui

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
    frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
    frame.setLineWidth(3)
    frame.setAutoFillBackground(True)
    palette = frame.palette()
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Background, QtGui.QColor("#ff00ff"))
    frame.setPalette(palette)

    widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    w_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(widget)
    w_layout.addWidget(frame)

    widget.resize(200, 200)
    widget.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: screenshot]